# Excel Find Function in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I tried searching the forum and also on the net but was not successful. I'm trying to search part of the value "TC1" in Column C using the below VBA code.

There are 2 values in Column C, "K3-TC1" which is in excel "C1" cell, and the other value as "K3-TC10" some where in the same column C.
While I'm using the below code its finding the cell value as "K3-TC10" but not in the 1st row of Column C which is "K3-TC1".

`Dim TCFind As Range
Set TCFind = Range("C:C").Find(What:="TC" & TCCpy, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True)`

I want to set the reference for later use. 
Could some one please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The search would find your cell ... if you repeated the search (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel). The problem is that the `Find` function begins its search **after** the top left cell, so in your case the first it comes across is "K3-TC10".

I'm sure there are better solutions than the one I'm about to give, but if I want to include the first cell in the range as the start point of a `Find` then I add one cell to the start of the search range:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim TCFind As Range
Dim TCCpy As Long

TCCpy = 1
With Sheet1
    Set rng = Union(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B"), .Range("C:C"))
End With
Set TCFind = rng.Find(What:="TC" & TCCpy, After:=rng.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True)
Debug.Print TCFind.Address
```